# How i can to create my custom AJAX DataGrid for ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, datagrid

How i can to create my custom AJAX DataGrid for ASP.NET? Thanks.

Comment: You should start by having some idea of what you are trying to do.

Comment: [This article](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/aspnetajaxgridandpager.aspx) will walk you through creating an ASP.NET Ajax Grid, complete with Pager.

Answer (score 1):

You can start from simple Repeater using ASP.NET+JQuery. Retrieve data from .NET JSON service and render using JavaScript. Example is [here](http://encosia.com/2008/06/26/use-jquery-and-aspnet-ajax-to-build-a-client-side-repeater/).